# Dynamic array of structure in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, structure

I am trying to create a dynamic array of structures using `malloc()`. I have looked at some other answers already on this forum, but I got lost in answers that weren't the same from one question to the next. Here's what I did so far:

```
//This is above main()

struct linesegs
{
float*X;
float*Y;
float*Z;
float*Q;
float*R;
float*S;
};

struct linesegs *LINE;

//Inside main() I have this:

LINE = malloc((facets*3)*sizeof(linesegs));

//Later on I access the struct like so:

LINE[variable].X = SomeFloatNumber
LINE[variable].Y = SomeFloatNumber
LINE[variable].Z = SomeFloatNumber
LINE[variable].Q = SomeFloatNumber
LINE[variable].R = SomeFloatNumber
LINE[variable].S = SomeFloatNumber
```

From what I have read the above should be very close to correct, but my compliler underlined the `=` in `LINE = malloc((facets*3)*sizeof(linesegs));` and gives the following error:

A value of type "void*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "linesegs"

The places I learned this from were not exactly clear what goes where, and in what order they should go. I tried moving stuff around and playing with the pointers to no avail. Hopefully this question will help others (and me) by providing one solid answer with no confusion =). Thanks in advance for help with this.

Comment: You need to cast the result of malloc() to the proper type.

Comment: Your compiler error seems to imply you are using C++ or a very old C compiler.

Comment: when I put `*linesegs` it says type name is not allowed. I am using a C++ / C compiler. Visual studio 2010 to be specific

Comment: Sorry, I mislead you. Try malloc((facets*3)*sizeof(struct linesegs));

Comment: It goes back to underlining the `=` sign and saying: A value of type "void*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "linesegs"

Comment: Are you compiling this in a .cpp file?

Comment: Given the error message, it seems like you have `struct linesegs LINE;`, and not `struct linesegs *LINE;` (i.e., you do not have a pointer).

Comment: sizeof(linesegs) is just plain wrong unless there is a "typedef struct linesegs linesegs" someplace. We don't have all the code, so we don't know.

Comment: This sounds like MSVC in C++ mode. Try building with /TC and see what happens.

Comment: It's not related to the question, but why are you assigning float numbers to float pointers? Aren't you getting type conversion errors there, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would this solve the error or warning?

```
LINE = (struct linesegs *)malloc((facets*3)*sizeof(struct linesegs));
```

Comment: I think it would, but I wonder why the cast is needed. C does not need it.

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to fix it =) Just wondering though, what's the difference between my way and yours?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using a c++ compiler which doesn't allow function cast...  your code would be ok in c.

Comment: Check your compiler documentation, there's probably an option to tell it to compile as C rather than C++.